# Input images with dynamic dimensions in Tensorflow-lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have a tensorflow model that takes input images of varying size:

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(128,None,1), name='x_input')

<tf.Tensor 'x_input:0' shape=(?, 128, ?, 1) dtype=float32>
```

When I convert this model to tensorflow-lite it complains:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert() 

ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension.
Tensor 'x_input_1' has invalid shape '[None, 128, None, 1]'.
```

I cannot scale my images to a fixed size. The only solution I see is to pad the images to some maximum size and use that one in the graph, but that seems pretty wasteful. Is there any other way to make tensorflow-lite work with dynamic image dimensions? And is there any rationale for this limitation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you **can use dynamic tensors** in TF-Lite. The reason why you can't directly set the shape to `[None, 128, None, 1]` is because this way, you can easily support more languages in the future. Furthermore, it makes the best use of static memory allocation scheme. This is a smart design choice for a framework that is intended to be used on small devices with low computation power.
Here are the steps on how to dynamically set the tensor's size:

#### 0. Freezing

It seems like you're converting from a frozen GraphDef, i.e. a `*.pb` file. Suppose your frozen model has input shape `[None, 128, None, 1]`.

#### 1. Conversion step.

During this step, set the input size to **any valid one** that can be accepted by your model. For example:

```bash
tflite_convert \
  --graph_def_file='model.pb' \
  --output_file='model.tflite' \
  --input_shapes=1,128,80,1 \     # <-- here, you set an
                                  #     arbitrary valid shape
  --input_arrays='input' \         
  --output_arrays='Softmax'
```

#### 2. Inference step

The trick is to use the function `interpreter::resize_tensor_input(...)` of the TF-Lite API in real time during inference. I will provide a python implementation of it. The Java and C++ implementation should be the same (as they have similar API):

```python
from tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import interpreter

# Load the *.tflite model and get input details
model = Interpreter(model_path='model.tflite')
input_details = model.get_input_details()

# Your network currently has an input shape (1, 128, 80 , 1),
# but suppose you need the input size to be (2, 128, 200, 1).
model.resize_tensor_input(
    input_details[0]['index'], (2, 128, 200, 1))
model.allocate_tensors()
```

That's it. You can now use that model for images with shape `(2, 128, 200, 1)`, as long as your network architecture allows such an input shape. Beware that you will have to do `model.allocate_tensors()` every time you do such a reshape, so it will be very inefficient. It is **strongly recommended** to avoid  using this function too much in your program.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer no longer works with newer version of Tensorflow. One should use shape None instead of a dummy shape in conversion step, and then it works by using interpreter.resizeInput(). See here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41807