# Tensorflow: TFLiteConverter (Saved Model -> TFLite) requires all operands and results to have compatible element types

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have been stuck with this issue for a few days now, but when I am trying to convert my `saved_model.pb` file to a `.tflite` model, using the code below, it gives an error (stack trace below).

---

Conversion Code:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(
    "/tmp/test_saved_model2")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
quantized_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(quantized_model)
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 196, in toco_convert_protos
    model_str = wrap_toco.wrapped_toco_convert(model_flags_str,
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\wrap_toco.py", line 32, in wrapped_toco_convert
    return _pywrap_toco_api.TocoConvert(
Exception: <unknown>:0: error: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): requires all operands and results to have compatible element types
<unknown>:0: note: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): see current operation: %1 = "tf.Identity"(%arg0) {device = ""} : (tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>) -> tensor<1x?x?x3xui8>


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Data/TFOD/tflite_converter.py", line 27, in <module>
    quantized_model = converter.convert()
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 1076, in convert
    return super(TFLiteConverterV2, self).convert()
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 899, in convert
    return super(TFLiteFrozenGraphConverterV2,
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 629, in convert
    result = _toco_convert_impl(
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 569, in toco_convert_impl
    data = toco_convert_protos(
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 202, in toco_convert_protos
    raise ConverterError(str(e))
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: <unknown>:0: error: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): requires all operands and results to have compatible element types
<unknown>:0: note: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): see current operation: %1 = "tf.Identity"(%arg0) {device = ""} : (tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>) -> tensor<1x?x?x3xui8>
```

---

I have tried using `tf-nightly`, and although it works, it doesn't create a "FlatBuffer" model which I need for using it on an Android Phone. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 points where you should pay attention to:

1. > (tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>) -> tensor<1x?x?x3xui8>

Looks like your model has dynamic shape, and tflite [does not work well](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24607) with them. First of all convert your model from saved_model to tflite with fixed input. See good way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701663/input-images-with-dynamic-dimensions-in-tensorflow-lite) e.g.:

```
tflite_convert \
  --saved_model_dir="/tmp/test_saved_model2" \
  --output_file='model.tflite' \
  --input_shapes=1,256,256,3 \     # <-- here, you set an
                                  #     arbitrary valid shape
  --input_arrays='input' \         
  --output_arrays='Softmax'
```

Another way is to make your saved_model with fixed input-output shape so you do not need to specify it during saved_model->lite conversion. And this is the [only](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30180#issuecomment-505959220) option for TF2

2. > converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

During debugging process try to avoid any kind of optimizations so you will have less places to search for your bug. This is general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue before, and now can train tflite model with following 3 steps:

1. training the data

   !python /content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py 
   --pipeline_config_path={pipeline_config_path} 
   --model_dir={model_dir} 
   --alsologtostderr 
   --num_train_steps={num_steps} 
   --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 
   --num_eval_steps={num_eval_steps}
2. export tflite 2 graph:

   !python models/research/object_detection/export_tflite_graph_tf2.py 
   --pipeline_config_path={pipeline_config_path} 
   --trained_checkpoint_dir={model_dir} --output_directory=tflite_exported
3. convert .pb to tflite

   !tflite_convert --output_file 'model.tflite' --saved_model_dir 'tflite_exported/saved_model'